# negative powers 8051

Tags: 8051, math-notation

I am attempting to create a calculator using Keil C51 compiling for a DS89c450 target device, but I have run into an obstacle with regards to negative powers. The compiler keeps returning errors when ever I attempt to calculate the inverse of a trigonometric function and a run time error (a null response) occurs when I try negative powers. I believe the documentation states this isn't possible, is it possible with the default math.h or, if not, how would I go about achieving this?

To clarify, this is being completed in C, to assembly.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You're using the floating point version of the function?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have only tried using int/long inputs, although I have been storing the potential output (excepting the error) in a float. If you refer to a seperate function, that is, other than pow(number, power), then no, I haven't but would love to know of it.

Comment: It might have been a few years, but surely you have been shown a way to express this value with a positive exponent...

Comment: non-integer powers of a negative number are supposed to give you a domain error, but that would be a run-time error not a 'compiler error'. Please supply the smallest code fragment and exact error message that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Now that you mention it, yes, that would be entirely viable. Just didn't even think of it. More the worry is it isn't even history, I haven't even finished school yet!

Comment: My mistake @SpehroPefhany the inverse of trigonometric function causes the compiler error, the normal inverses do not, they cause run time error as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Negative powers are equal to the inverse of the original to the power of the absolute original value. That is to say:

x^-y = 1/x^y

With regards to inverse trigonometric functions, the inverse of a function is also known as the arc of it. eg;
sin^-1 = asin
cos^-1 = acos
tan^-1 = atan

Thanks to Chris Stratton for that helpful reminder!